# Is the only way to send payments through the adapative payment api?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-rest-sdk

I couldn't find anything in the classic or rest api for sending payments. I want to send payments, is the adaptive payment api the best way to go to sending individual payments? (I'm buying products and want to send them automaticially)

Answer (score 0):

Mass Payments (classic) and Payouts (REST) both send payments to other users, and while these can be used to send sets of payments they can also send one payment at a time. Many merchants use these products this way.

Comment: Do you know if theres anything in the api to make them pay the fees? I think i could only find that in the adapative one